# I want to get the data as zero for the date where data's are not present

Tags: sql, oracle

Query:

```
select logindate, count(*) as people 
from authortable 
group by logindate 
order by logindatedesc nulls last
```

Output:

```
logindate   people 
6-oct-2014    5
5-oct-2014    7
4-oct-2014    4
3-oct-2014    8
2-oct-2014    0
1-oct-2014    0
30-sept-2014  5
29-sept-2014  7
28-sept-2014  4
27-sept-2014  8
```

I am getting the data I required, but I want something as if there is no login on a particular day, it should return 0 ..  as in 1 and 2 oct. I want to get the data for 1 and 2 as shown above.

For now I am not getting 1 and 2 oct rows as no data is present

Comment: in the above code there are two colums as logindate and people and the corresponding datas are eg: 6-oct-2014   5

Comment: Do you want to cover *all* dates between some start and end date or is there some other table containing rows which indicate "interesting" dates?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i want to cover all dates between start and end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which generate the missing date rows:

```
with daterange as
  (select min(logindate) startdate
        , max(logindate) enddate
   from authortable)
, dates as
  (select startdate + (level-1) logindate
   from daterange
   connect by startdate + (level-1) <= enddate)
, logincount as
  (select logindate
        , count(*) people
   from authortable
   group by logindate)
select d.logindate
     , nvl(l.people, 0) people
from logincount l
     right outer join dates d
       on (d.logindate = l.logindate)
order by d.logindate desc nulls last
```

EDIT: Added missing `group_by` (as noted by nop77svk)